# Set internalDateSource in Gmail API message upload

Tags: google-apps, gmail-api

I'm trying to import messages from imap to Gmail via [Gmail API v1](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert). If I use the API call for insert, I can specify internalDateSource to dateHeader. With that setting the message will display the original sent date in Gmail, instead of the import date.

If I use the [Gmail API Upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert) method, I don't see any option to specify the internalDateSource in the multipart message header. So Gmail will use the latest receive header, which is the import.

```
Received: from 661831859263-hlgnfsakj37rged896gvl0mitub85lii.apps.googleusercontent.com
named unknown
by gmailapi.google.com
with HTTPREST;
Wed, 4 Mar 2015 00:01:04 -0800
```

Any ideas how to display the original delivery or sent date in Gmail when uploading a message via upload request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`internalDateSource` should be set as part of the URI, not a header:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/<userId>/messages?internalDateSource=dateHeader
```

also, be aware that [messages.insert()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert) does not de-duplicate mail nor does it do automatic threading. For migrating mail from another system, [messages.import()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/import) is probably the better choice.

It's definitely worth reading through the [Migrating from the Email Migration API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-emapi) page for some pointers.

Comment: ok, I'll change y program to import instead of insert. But with [messages.import](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/import) labels can't be added on the fly. So I have to do one or more API calls to add and remove labels, right?

Comment: I figured it out: you can use labels like you do on an insert message, if you upload via an multipart request. Thanks Jay!